# Adding an azure web app into a App service environment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application on Azure which was NOT created in an App  Service Environment (ASE). Now I have a specific requirement that forces me to create an ASE and add the existing web application into the ASE. Is it doable ? How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a WebApp to be inside an ASE, it has to belong to an AppServicePlan whose Location is name of the ASE and is of Premium Sku. For that reason you can't change the AppServicePlan of your existing WebApp and point it to that in the ASE.

What you can do is Clone the App , for you to be able to do this

1) You need to have an AppServicePlan inside ASE that is tied to a worker pool. If not already present, create a new AppServicePlan and select the ASE you created as the Location.

2) In your existing WebApp Settings there is an options to Clone (if not already in Premium SKU, it will ask you to upgrade). You can use this option to create a copy of your WebApp inside the ASE and tie to the AppServicePlan you created in step above.

Here's a link that provides info on how to clone a WebApp into an existing AppServicePlan : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

Comment: Or simply redeploy your application to an App Service Plan inside ASE.

Comment: Yes, you always have that option of simply redeploy the webapp into ASE :)

Comment: If you can't redeploy (as in "misplaced" the project source code) you probably have bigger problems to worry about anyway. amirite?