# Azure App Service Environment App service plan hosting not associated with ASE

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I followed the steps which are described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358173/adding-an-azure-web-app-into-a-app-service-environment/42682295) to clone a web app to ASE. But it still does not associate itself in a hosting plan with the ASE.

[Here i created the App Service Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkiIW.png)

[But the result is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4cCK.png)

What other step is needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What other step is needed to achieve this?

No more steps are required. It may be an issue of Azure portal yesterday. I also can’t create a Web App Plan in ASE.  The issue seems has been fixed today. I can create an Web App Plan in ASE now. 
Please redo your steps to clone your app to ASE.

Comment: It's true, today I can do it without problems.
Clearly it was a Microsoft Azure bug

Thanks!